# Google signOut doesn't forget e-mail/password

Tags: ios, swift, google-plus

I'm trying to make a multi user app for IOS. I've faced a problem with google+.

After signOut, if i try to sign in again, it still has my user data and jumps to the permissions view, without asking for e-mail and password for a new authentication.

I've already used disconnect() and signOut() and still jumps to the permission view.

[image: Permissions View]

The code for signOut button:

```
GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
```

Or:

```
// Disconnects the user from the app and revokes previous authentication.
// If the operation succeeds, the OAuth 2.0 token is also removed from keychain.
// The token is needed to disconnect so do not call |signOut| if |disconnect| is
// to be called.
GPPSignIn.sharedInstance().disconnect()
```

btw: every thing else works(sharing posts, a good GPPSignIn.sharedInstance through the app)

Regards AdS

Comment: I am facing this problem now. Any solutions?

Comment: I agree. Same problem. Any solution?